# MacBook Air stuck at login screen, can't get into safe boot nor into Recovery Mode

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, login

Last night I kept my MacBook Air on sleep mode and in morning when I tried to login, it got stuck at login screen with progressive bar completed but there was no further action.

The screen is completely stuck at login, I tried safe boot but the Mac again stuck at Apple logo screen with progressive bar completely stuck at 100 percent, I also tried to get into Recovery Mode but same problem occurred as in the  safe boot.

The computer is a 1.5 year old MacBook Air running macOS High Sierra.

Comment: Have you attempted internet recovery.

Comment: Yes , i did the internet recovery the globe and progressive bar gets completed and the next screen is again a apple logo with  progressive  stuck at 100 percent

Comment: Got my mac working as it was a hardware issue , Control unit was replaced

Comment: please add as answer and mark as solved